# AngularJS How would one run two controllers from one website, and have one of them change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

## The problem

I'm trying to right an AngularJS web page, and I have variables stored in a controller. This controller is bound to the first tab. I want to be able to access the variables belonging to this controller (and keep a loop running), from a second tab (with it's own controller). When I change tabs, it loses focus of the first controller, and resets the variables when I swap back onto it.

## Possible Fix?

Having a main controller running across all tabs, and have that run the loop and store all the important variables. Then have the individual tab's controller just access the methods/variables from this controller.

Comment: check out using a Service to share the data across both controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First what is interesting is why you are using loops for update variables? [use $watch()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

In general there are couple ways to share variables across angular application.

1. You can use nested controllers and share variables in parent controller. You will have $scope.$parent.variable but angular will do this for you and you can just call it by $scope.variable. Than all child controllers will share its parents variables. [see angular ui router nesting](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)
2. Have service to store shared variable. In this case you will need to have  some way to update service variable every time something changes in any controller. For this you can use [$scope.$watch()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) method and for every property change update your model in service.

Personally I prefer first approach just because binding is done in angular and save you some code you will need for service approach.

Reason why one controller's "loop" stops is probably because of $digest cycle of your controller is not running. [see more to understand how $digest cycle actually works](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Comment: I'm using the loop to update variables every frame, as far as I understand $watch() is for events, correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Why update variables every frame? Basically for every action there is event in JS. Without action there should not be anything you need to update. Can you be more specific? Like if you want to update variables base on some response from server, event to updated variables will be triggered by angular. If you want to update base on user interaction same thing, angular should take care of it.

Comment: This is basically what I have, but in my code it works. Every second I need to add to a counter.
https://jsfiddle.net/8g725rmk/2/

Comment: this is fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/8g725rmk/5/, Main issues there were that $count need to be $scope variable (or controller this.$count but than you need to specify controller as) in order to bind itself, and timer needed time for looping. Your app also was getter not setter for module [] were missing angular.module('app',[]). This is not a bug but your functions like loop doesn't need to be as $scope functions in your specific case, unless you want to use them as ng-click or so.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you work with a Service and inject this service in your 2 controllers?
Then each controller can have access to the service and share the same variables.

Perhaps a fiddle might help?

Comment: This is what I am doing currently, it works in my code, but for some reason it is not working here (Probably some rookie error).https://jsfiddle.net/8g725rmk/1/

Answer (score 0):

[$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) seems like the easiest fix here.  Add $rootScope as a Dependency and then assign your data to it.

Something link this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('Controller1', function($rootScope, $scope) {

  $scope.root = $rootScope;

  // Test data 
  $rootScope.something = $rootScope.something || "really important";

});

angular.module('app').controller('Controller2', function($rootScope, $scope) {

  $scope.root = $rootScope;

  // Test data 
  $rootScope.something = $rootScope.something || "even better!";

});
```

If that feels "hacky", well it kinda is.  This is a great reason to learn and use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Simple Service to hold my stuff.
 */

angular.module('app').factory('Stuff', function() {

  // This is the Stuff object.  
  // The factory makes stuff as a service when AngularJS starts up.
  // Whenever you put 'Stuff' as a Dependency, Angular will use the first one it made.
  // So all your controllers share the same Stuff object.
  var stuff = {
    // We're just going to keep one thing.
    justOneThing: null
  };

  // These are example functions.  A getter and a setter
  // You could get stuff.justOneThing directly, or use functions
  // Or write anything you like.
  stuff.set = function(value) {
    return stuff.justOneThing = value;
  };

  stuff.get = function() {
    return stuff.justOneThing;
  }

  // This returns the Stuff object.  I like this pattern for services
  // and use it alot.  It's easy for me to see what the factory made
  // and what the service is doing.  THere's other options!
  return stuff;
});
```

Comment: Root scope is cross application. I will avoid using it just because anything in application can change it and you have no real control over it.

Comment: As much as I have tried, I believe you cannot bind data to $rootScope variables from within a html view.

Comment: Aha!  Yes, because you can only access $scope.  The hack is to put $rootScope on $scope.  See edits...